# Add script if condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I'm trying to add a script to a page only if the page url does not contain the word 'cms'. This is because the script breaks the backend of the page but works fine on the front end.

This is what I have so far;

```
<script>
     if(window.location.href.indexOf("cms") == -1) {
          $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us17.list-manage.com","uuid":"INSERT_STRING","lid":"INSERT_STRING"}) })</script>');
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work; the error I get in my code editor is unclosed string literal. I think the problem is the fact that it thinks I'm closing the script tag and then giving it more JS after that. I've tried swapping round the quotes but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to make your check, then IF you need to add a script make an AJAX call to get it.

Comment: You could use use the eval function instead of append a script block

Comment: may be : if((window.location.href).indexOf("cms") === -1) {

Comment: First - you say the error is in your code editor.  Not all editors are perfect - have you tried running this? Does it _run_? If it runs, who cares what the editor says.  Second, if it does _not_ run, then you need to include the specific error(s) are, including which file is throwing the error.

Comment: I would add this logic in the server side template. What CMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to dynamically add script with some content w/o ajax-downloading it:

```
var x = document.createElement("script");
x.textContent = "window.test = function(){console.log('xx')}";
document.head.appendChild(x)
```

Running

```
test()
```

In console will trigger the method after that.

But in  your case, however, it is a bit more complicated, because you are adding 2 scripts at the same time. Problem with dynamically loaded scripts is that you have to take special care to load them in order.

Tbh, I am a bit unclear about your problem if script breaking backend vs. working on the front end. How exactly pages with cms are different from the rest?

On a side note, adding scripts dynamically on the front-end is quite difficult to do right. If you are doing it to fix a problem - there are probably easier/better solutions